# Android layout, how to specify the order of elements before calling addView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm using AdWhirl to place an ad in my free app.  I want the ad to appear below a MapView and above a ListView.  No matter what I try, I can't get the ad to appear anywhere except the bottom.  Currently, the listView is inflated in the XML, but the AdWhirlView must be created in the Java code.  Since I'm calling addView(adWhirlView) on a LinearLayout with orientation vertical, the ad always appears on the bottom.  How can I define where the ad ought to be placed?

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"           
            android:id="@+id/layout_main"
            >  
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1">            


            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                ....

       </RelativeLayout>                 


            <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"          
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"           
        android:id="@+id/layout_main"
        >  
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">            


        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            ....

   </RelativeLayout>                 

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_ad"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"          
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then use use following code

```
AdManager.setTestDevices(new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR });
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_ad);
AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, "Key");
Display d = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(d.getWidth(), 52);
layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, adWhirlLayoutParams);
layout.invalidate();
```

This way your list view will always comes after AdWhirl and if there is no ads to display then listview comes just after map

Comment: perfect!  in the end, i was missing android:layout_height="wrap_content"